# Using Angular 2 I am trying to take values from UI to server... Please look into it

Tags: angular-material

There is a text box and a checkbox. Users can enter values and hit enter, a similar pair of textbox and checkbox will again open up - this will continue. User can add or delete values which should accordingly reflect in the server and should also reflect on the UI fetching from the server.

How do I go about this? It's like an array of objects where each object is a pair of textbox and checkbox values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a FormGroup including a FormArray composed of texfields and checkbox.

You can add (or remove) items to the array and then finally get a JSON containing all values and send to to the server with some http POST call.

You could also get a JSON element from server with http GET call and populate FormGroup (form) with form.patchValue().

FormGroup, FormArray, Http service, Observable are main topics to explore.